# Tree Structure Links

Tags: c++, qt, pointers, hyperlink, tree

I already have a full functional tree structure with Items. Every Item is unique because I've given a ID.

I want to implement links, like links in a filesystem from one node to another (e.g. link to folder or link to file).

I would like just to add pointer (link) to the tree that points to the object (target) to jump from one path to another.

Heres an example of that what I want to achieve:

```
Section 1
    Item 1
    Item 2
Section 2
    Item 1
    Item 2
    Section 3
        Item 1
        Item 2 (Link) --> Section 1 - Item 2
```

The only good idea I had is to store all Items in a QHash first and afterwards build the menu-tree by using pointer out of the QHash (refered by ID).

Do you know a way to link between Items without using the QHash?

Comment: Are you using model for your tree view? What means "jump from one path to another."?

Comment: I'm using a flat Listmodel because I'm building a touch Interface. It is always only shown one node with the appended childitems (menu). I want to "jump" from one menu to another.

Comment: @vahancho I'm still looking for a solution for my problem. It would be nice to get some help.